# How to pass a variable in the select-string of powershell

Tags: windows, powershell, powershell-2.0

There is one requirement where i need to pass a variable that is set in the powershell to the another variable

Please find the below example

```
    PS D:\temp\arun> $match1=get-date -format ddMMM
    PS D:\temp\arun> $match1
    19Jun
```

test.txt file has the below content

```
    19Jun1
    19Jun2
    19Jun3

    PS D:\temp\arun> $match2=select-string -simple 19Jun test.txt
    PS D:\temp\arun> $match2
    19Jun1
    19Jun2
    19Jun3
```

But when i am trying to pass the variable i am not getting the result.

```
    PS D:\temp\arun> $match2=select-string -simple $match1 test.txt
    PS D:\temp\arun> $match2
```

Could any one please help me in this?

Comment: Works for me as expected. Is there anything in your script that might interfere with $match1 or change its value?

Comment: What the output you are getting @ShayLevy 
I am not getting any output

Comment: @ShayLevy when i tried again it worked..sorry for the trouble. :)
Happy now :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Works fine here. Try specifying the paramters to make sure the right value is assigned to the right parameter.

```
$match2 = Select-String -SimpleMatch -Pattern $match1 -Path .\test.txt
```