# Select a particular type of word from a text file and load it in a Variable

Tags: regex, powershell, select-string

I am trying to  use a power shell script to  read the contents of a file and pick a specific type of word from it. I need to load the word  that is found as a variable which I intend to use further downstream.

This is how my input file looks like:

```
{
    "AvailabilityZone": "ap-northeast-1b", 
    "VolumeType": "gp2", 
    "VolumeId": "vol-087238f9", 
    "State": "creating", 
    "Iops": 100, 
    "SnapshotId": "", 
    "CreateTime": "2016-09-15T12:17:27.952Z", 
    "Size": 10
}
```

The  specific word I would like to pick is `vol-xxxxxxxx`.
I used this link  to write my script
[How to pass a variable in the select-string of powershell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17188088/how-to-pass-a-variable-in-the-select-string-of-powershell?answertab=active#tab-top)

This is how I am doing it:

---

```
$Filename = "c:\reports\volume.jason"
$regex = "^[vol-][a-z0-9]{8}$"
$newvolumeid=select-string -Pattern $regex -Path $filename > C:\Reports\newVolumeid.txt
$newVolumeid
```

---

When I run this script it runs but does not give any response. Seems somehow  the output of select string is not loaded into the variable `$newvolumeid`.

Any idea how to resolve this? Or what I am missing?

PS: The post mentioned above is about 3 years old and doesn't work hence I am reposting.

Comment: is the file in `json`? if so [check this post out](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16575419/powershell-retrieve-json-object-by-field-value)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to read a property of a JSON object. Instead of using regex, you can parse the JSON and select the property using:

```
Get-Content 'c:\reports\volume.jason' | ConvertFrom-Json | select -ExpandProperty VolumeId
```

Comment: Awsome,  this works. i am able to get the info neatly.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$Inpath = "E:\tests\test.txt"

$INFile = Get-Content $Inpath 

$NeedsTrimming = $INFile.Split(" ") | ForEach-Object {if ($_ -like '*vol-*'){$_}}

$FirstQuote = $NeedsTrimming.IndexOf('"')
$LastQuote = $NeedsTrimming.LastIndexOf('"')

$vol = $NeedsTrimming.Substring(($FirstQuote + 1),($LastQuote - 1))

$vol
```

Comment: While your solution may work, it is very error prone and not recommendable.